# Copy contents of XML tag into a new set of XML tags

Tags: xml, linux, sed

I am trying to process an XML file using only Linux CLI tools.
The main problem that I am trying to solve is to copy the contents of a specific XML tag into a new tag, like so:

```
<date>Wednesday</date>
<name>The Name</name>
<anotherattribute>Attribute</anotherattribute>
```

into:

```
<date>Wednesday</date>
<id>The Name</id>
<name>The Name</name>
<anotherattribute>Attribute</anotherattribute>
```

I have been trying to use sed to solve this problem, and have been able to identify the tag, and copy it into the hold buffer:

```
/<name>/{
h
i\
<id>
G
a\
</id>
}
```

but that results in:

```
<date>Wednesday</date>
<id>
<name>The Name</name>
<name>The Name</name>
</id>
<anotherattribute>Attribute</anotherattribute>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Using `sed` this way is a really bad idea. Not as bad as trying to parse HTML with a regex, but still pretty bad. Check out the second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/<name>/{h;s/name>/id>/g;G}'
```

---

You can also try `xmlstarlet`:

```
cat input.xml |
    xmlstarlet ed -i //name -t elem -n id -v '' |
        xmlstarlet ed -u //id -x '../name'
```