# Read from xml to bash

Tags: xml, bash, shell

Newbie in shell scripting here. How do i read, for example, every name from following xml code and put all names in columns?

```
<rates>
   <currency>
      <name>Australian dollar</name>
      <rate>2.34</rate>
      <amount>1</amount>
   </currency>
   <currency>
      <name>GB Pounds</name>
      <rate>4.12</rate>
      <amount>1</amount>
   </currency>
   <currency>
      <name>Euro</name>
      <rate>3.45</rate>
      <amount>1</amount>
   </currency>
   <currency>
      <name>USA dollar</name>
      <rate>2.55</rate>
      <amount>1</amount>
   </currency>
   <currency>
      <name>Russian ruble</name>
      <rate>7.72</rate>
     <amount>100</amount>
   </currency>
```

Comment: [How to parse XML in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

As someone noted, 'sed' is a fine way to extract a given element from an XML file -- so long as your actual XML is as simple as the example OP gave. But beware of cases like:

- Elements that aren't complete and alone on one line
- Elements that can nest, like HTML lists or divs or spans....
- Data that looks like tags but isn't -- because it's escaped, for example being inside CDATA marked sections, processing instructions, or comments.

You can sometimes handle such cases by re-line-breaking messy data first, say, so the start-tag you want to match is always at the start of a line.

If you want to get multiple elements, cover more general cases, etc., it will take a little more work. One of many ways is to convert to something trivial like CSV (I have Perl scripts out there called 'xml2tab' and 'tab2xml' that I use for this all the time).

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed, if you just want to extract specific tag value from xml file.

```
 sed  -n 's/.*<name>\(.*\)<\/name>/\1/p' test.txt

 #extract and print comma separated list
 sed  -n 's/.*<name>\(.*\)<\/name>/\1/p' t1.txt | tr '\n' ','
```