# Periodically Crawl a Feed xml and get Specific field from Xml Using Bash Script

Tags: xml, bash, rss

I have an Application which needs to periodically crawl from a Feed server, let a news website and then parse the Feed xml to print specific Feeds .

Let the News Feed Url is : http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113,

I want to extract the item/title, item/description and item/category fields.
I will crawl the Url after a particular interval and parse the xml and print this fields , How to do this using Bash Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For periodic task execution you should use probably use the `cron` utility, which is explained well in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368). Using this you can set your script to run in specified intervals.

XML parsing in bash has a quite lengthy example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585), and you should be able to find other examples on this site.