# Replace filed value in xml in a particular record ID and also depending on the other key value using bash scripts

Tags: xml, bash

I have an xml file :

```
<record name="rfPathProv">
        <key name="pathId" value="1"/>
        <key name="pathDirection" value="RX"/>
        <field name="band" value="4"/>
</record>
<record name="rfPathProv">
        <key name="pathId" value="1"/>
        <key name="pathDirection" value="TX"/>
        <field name="band" value="4"/>
</record>
```

I need to replace the band value only if the record name="rfPathProv" and key name="pathId" value="1" using bash scripts. please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [parsing the xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash) and then working from there?

Comment: I did this :

sed -i '/<record name="rfPathProv">/,/<\/record>/s/field name="band" value="*"/field name="band" value='\"$bandLte\"'/' $file

but i need to know how to check pathId" value="1" before replacing the band value. Kind of stuck here

Comment: please learn to include your attempts to solve your problem with code INTO the body of the question. It should be formatted as you have done with the XML sample. Much easier to read that way. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below, by no means is it perfect at all. In this example I am changing band value to 10.

```
awk '/<\/record>/{a=0};{
a+=sub(/<record name="rfPathProv">/,"&")
a+=sub(/<key name="pathId" value="1"\/>/,"&")
    if (a==2) {
      sub(/<field name="band" value="[0-9]+"/,"&@")
      sub(/"[0-9]+"@/,"\"10\"")
              }
}1' originalfile > newfile
```

Comment: Hi Ell, 
 
The above solution is only printing the updated value on the console but the values are not getting updated in the .xml file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use a redirect to send the output data to a new file. I've updated the code so that it will do this. Just replace the band value obviously, with whatever it should be and the file names.

Comment: Hi Ell, 

Thanks for the support. I have posted one more issue. can you please comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an xpath problem. Using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), you can do

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//record[@name="rfPathProv" and ./key[@name="pathId" and @value="1"]]/field[@name="band"]/@value' -v 'newValue' file.xml > newfile.xml
```

output (after providing a top-level node to the sample xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<records>
  <record name="rfPathProv">
    <key name="pathId" value="1"/>
    <key name="pathDirection" value="RX"/>
    <field name="band" value="newValue"/>
  </record>
  <record name="rfPathProv">
    <key name="pathId" value="1"/>
    <key name="pathDirection" value="TX"/>
    <field name="band" value="newValue"/>
  </record>
</records>
```

Comment: I need to use only bash scripts.

Comment: So, sed/awk/grep are disallowed as well? xmlstarlet is just a program that can be called *from* a bash script like any other program.

Comment: can use sed,awk and grep

Comment: Sounds like arbitrary constraints. Is this homework?

Comment: nope. i need to use this script to modify xml and i'm new to shell scripting

Comment: OK, I get it. But it sounds to me like you are fixated on learning how to parse XML with sed. Parsing XML **requires** a proper XML parser. You need to be flexible enough to recognize the right tool for the job.