# Problems with parsing xml with bash

Tags: xml, bash

I'm using the `read_dom` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash) to parse some XML.

```
#!/bin/bash
read_dom ()
{
    local IFS=\>
    read -d \< ENTITY CONTENT
    local ret=$?
    TAG_NAME=${ENTITY%% *}
    ATTRIBUTES=${ENTITY#* }
    return $ret
}
while read_dom; do
    echo "$ENTITY => $CONTENT"
done < test.xml
```

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo bar="baz">
    <d>
        <a>
            <b>qux</b><c />
        </a>
        <a>
            <b>buzz</b>
        </a>
    </d>
</foo>
```

All except the `</foo>` is not being parsed:

```
$ ./xmlparser.sh
[...]    
a =>

b => buzz
/b =>

/a =>

/d =>
```

I cannot figure out where the problem would be, since all other end tags except `</foo>` are being parsed. Could someone help?

Comment: It is because of EOF is reached. Try printing "$ENTITY => $CONTENT" and ret value in your read_dom function and you will be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to see the last line because you are passing the file using STDIN to the read_dom function and you have echo statement inside while loop which will never be called once the EOF is reached. You can use the below code-

```
#!/bin/bash
read_dom ()
{
    local IFS=\>
    line=$@
    str=$(echo $line | awk -v FS="(\>|\<)" 2>/dev/null '{print $2}')
    eval x=($str)
    ENTITY=${x[0]}
    CONTENT=${x[1]}
    TAG_NAME=${ENTITY%% *}
    ATTRIBUTES=${ENTITY#* }
 }
while read line; do
    read_dom $line
    echo "$ENTITY => $CONTENT"
done < xml
```