# find links with regex

Tags: linux, sed

I am currently trying to learn Linux commands and regular expressions, I am stuck on a little problem that I have trying to find a series of links within a file using sed and regular expressions, can anyone help me work this out and where I am going wrong. The links are something like this

```
<a href="../a-lot-of-different/words-that/should-link.html">Useful links</a>
<a href="..//a-lot-of-different/words-that/should-find-lots-of-links.html">Multiple links</a>
<a href="../another-word-and-links/multiple-words/sjshfi-dfg.html">more links</a>
```

This is what I have.

```
sed -n '/<a*href=”^[../"]*\([a-z]*\)^[.html](["]*\)/p' /file > newfile
```

Comment: If it's an HTML file, I recommend using a DOM parser. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6389/parse-html-on-linux and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are less than ideal for parsing HTML.

You didn't show your desired output.  I am guessing that you want to extract the links.  if so, try:

```
$ sed -rn 's/.*<a\s+href="([^"]*)".*/\1/p' file
../a-lot-of-different/words-that/should-link.html
..//a-lot-of-different/words-that/should-find-lots-of-links.html
../another-word-and-links/multiple-words/sjshfi-dfg.html
```

How it works:

- `.*<a\s+href="`

  This matches everything before the link.
- `([^"]*)`

  This matches the link and captures it into group `\1`.
- `".*`

  This matches the double-quote after the line and everything that follows.

Comment: Thank you for this, it has made it a lot clearer and it has found one of the links that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As anchor tag contain `href` tag, so searching `href` will solve the problem

```
sed -n '/href=".*"/p' link_file.txt
```