# replace one attribute on another with sed or awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

```
 <testcase classname='tc1' name='tc1' time='78.455094'/>
  <testcase classname='tc2' name='tc2' time='78.549320'>
    <failure type='fail-verdict'>
      error message
    </failure>
  </testcase>
  <testcase classname='tc3' name='tc_3' time='78.444719'/>
```

how to replace 3-rd attribute `time` in testcase tag to attribute `status` (status="pass" or "failure" based on testcase; for example: tc1,tc3 - pass, tc2- fail). I tried sed: `sed -i 's/time=\'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'/status="pass"/g' file.txt` firstly without any logic..but it doesn't work.

Comment: As suggested many times before on SO, you should reconsider if regex is the right tool to manipulate XML.

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output given that input.

Comment: not actual question now. I've already made it with the help in answer below

Answer (score 1):

You need the `-E` option (and `-r` for gnu sed) to use [ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere) (`+` and more) or you should use `[0-9][0-9]*`

You cannot escape singlequotes inside single quotes, you need to do the following:

```
% echo 'hello'\'' world'
hello' world
```

Applied to your command:

```
sed -i 's/time='\''[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*'\''/status="pass"/g' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks. It corectly changes the first part of my task.

Comment: the one thing remains here: how can I modify the previous line of the file if in the next line I've found <failure type='fail-verdict'> tag? Is it possible with sed or I should use grep or awk?

Comment: @Wlodek If you are using gnu sed you can use the `-z` modifier which will slurp the whole file into "one line" and you can then match on `\n` for newlines. But as I said in regex is not suited to parse / modify xml

Comment: what do you recommend instead?

Comment: @Wlodek You might want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash