# Trimming string up to certain characters in Bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, posix, trim

I'm trying to make a bash script that will tell me the latest stable version of the Linux kernel.

The problem is that, while I can remove everything **after** certain characters, I don't seem to be able to delete everything prior to certain characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

wget=$(wget --output-document - --quiet www.kernel.org | \grep -A 1 "latest_link")

wget=${wget##.tar.xz\">}

wget=${wget%</a>}

echo "${wget}"
```

Somehow the output "ignores" the `wget=${wget##.tar.xz\">}` line.

Comment: It's not good practice to make a variable with the same name as a command.

Comment: Instead of parsing the kernel.org HTML use the RSS feed to get the version. https://www.kernel.org/feeds/kdist.xml Then its just a matter of parsing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying remove the longest match of the pattern `.tar.xz\">` from the beginning of the string, but your string doesn't start with `.tar.xz`, so there is no match.

You have to use

```
wget=${wget##*.tar.xz\">}
```

Then, because you're in a script and not an interactive shell, there shouldn't be any need to escape `\grep` (presumably to prevent usage of an alias), as aliases are disabled in non-interactive shells.

And, as pointed out, naming a variable the same as an existing command (often found: `test`) is bound to lead to confusion.

If you want to use command line tools designed to deal with HTML, you could have a look at the [W3C HTML-XML-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) (Ubuntu: `apt install html-xml-utils`). Using them, you could get the info you want as follows:

```
$ curl -sL www.kernel.org | hxselect 'td#latest_link' | hxextract a -
4.10.8
```

Or, in detail:

```
curl -sL www.kernel.org |     # Fetch page
hxselect 'td#latest_link' |   # Select td element with ID "latest_link"
hxextract a -                 # Extract link text ("-" for standard input)
```

Comment: I used \grep simply because by default Ubuntu aliases grep to grep --color=auto. By calling the default grep I avoid colors in my output

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni Yes, but aliases are by default turned off in scripts, and `--color=auto` only prints terminal colour escape codes when printing to a tty, not in other cases, so it's not even a problem in an interactive session. Not really important, though.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll remove it.

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni I mean, it doesn't hurt, but it also doesn't really do anything ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need to extract a substring in bash I always see if I can brute force it in a couple of cut(1) commands. In your case, the following appears to work:

```
wget=$(wget --output-document - --quiet www.kernel.org | \grep -A 1 "latest_link")
echo $wget | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1
```

I'm certain there's a more elegant way, but this has simple syntax that I never forget. Note that it will break if 'wget' gets extra ">" or "<" characters in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use shell tools grep, awk, sed etc to parse HTML files.

However if you want a quick one liner then this awk should do the job:

```
get --output-document - --quiet www.kernel.org |
awk '/"latest_link"/ { getline; n=split($0, a, /[<>]/); print a[n-2] }'

4.10.8
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` method:

```
wget --output-document - --quiet www.kernel.org | \
  sed -n '/latest_link/{n;s/^.*">//;s/<.*//p}'
```

Output:

```
4.10.8
```