# How to run loop over xml file after extracting one value to extract other values in linux?

Tags: linux

I have to extract value (i.e. Value)  from large XML file based on other value (Package Name ), first removing duplicates then run a loop over it.

`grep -i 'abc.jar' /tmp/<filename>` ==> ***removing duplicates also***

output=>

```
<Package Name="abc.jar="OUI" Version="1.o">
<Property Name="InstallLocation" Value="/<some path>/abc.jar"/>
<Package Name="abc.jar" Evidence="OUI" Version="1.0">
<Property Name="InstallLocation" Value="/<some path/abc.jar"/>
<Package Name="abc.jar" Evidence="OUI" Version="1.0">
<Property Name="InstallLocation" Value="/<some path>/abc.jar"/>
```

I am able to extract all Package Name with below command but unable to proceed further.

```
grep -P -o -e '(?<=Package Name=").*?(?=")' <filename>
```

---

```
abc.jar
abc.jar
xyz.ear
xyz.ear
....contd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/893585/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe to `sort -u`:

```
grep -P -o -e '(?<=Package Name=").*?(?=")' <filename> | sort -u
```

The `-u` option:

```
 -u, --unique
         Unique keys.  Suppress all lines that have a key that is equal to an already processed one.
         This option, similarly to -s, implies a stable sort.  If used with -c or -C,
         sort also checks that there are no lines with duplicate keys.
```