# How to Get Min Number in a file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a `.config` file, In that file there is one variable `MinNumber` which contains some strings like `JAVA3.5, JAVA4.0, JAVA5`. Now I want to find minimum Java number using shell script.
`MinNumber = "JAVA3.5, JAVA4.0, JAVA5"`;

Logic should be first it should find `MinNumber` in a.config file and then check minimum java number.

Comment: What did you try, show us your code.

Comment: Actually I'm not getting logic for the same ..but i was trying to use awk command.

Comment: split string by comma, remove `JAVA` string and compare numbers.

Comment: @james : Is every variable defined in a separate line in the config file? Then `grep` for the line, and take out the arguments, for instance using `cut`.

Comment: and how to find that variable 'MinNumber ' in large file a.config file, we want to do operations on  value of 'MinNumber' only.

Comment: <Connector JAVAEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxSpareThreads="25" maxThreads="25" minSpareThreads="10" port="8444" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" server=" " MinNumber="CPP1.2, JAVA3.5, JAVA4.0, JAVA5"/>

Comment: from your last comment @james it looks like you could benefit from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash , that way you avoid problems with eventual multi-line MinNumer

Comment: Sorry i didn't find that link relatable to my question.
Now my question is very simple How to get value of MinNumber variable from a file which contains below information:

<Connector JAVAEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxSpareThreads="25" maxThreads="25" minSpareThreads="10" port="8444" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" server=" " MinNumber="CPP1.2, JAVA3.5, JAVA4.0, JAVA5"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
<Connector JAVAEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxSpareThreads="25" maxThreads="25" minSpareThreads="10" port="8444" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" server=" " MinNumber="CPP1.2, JAVA3.5, JAVA4.0, JAVA5"/>
```

One way:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=MinNumber=")[^"]+' file | sed "s/,/\n/g; s/ //g"  | sed -r 's/([^0-9\.]+)(.*)/\1 \2/' | awk '$2<min{min=$2;x=$1$2;}END{print x}' min=999
CPP1.2
```

Using the positive look behind(`(?<=MinNumber=")`) expression of Perl in grep, we extract the value of `MinNumber`. Using sed, we split the variable into multiple lines, and then using awk we got the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing how to extract the lowest string by just relying on standard text sorting.

First, set a shell variable to have a working example:

```
~ $ MinNumber="JAVA3.5, JAVA4.0, JAVA5"
```

Then use `tr` to replace single spaces with newlines, use `sed` to strip the commas, `sort` to order the output, then `head` to limit the line output to one line:

```
~ $ echo $MinNumber | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/,//' | sort | head -1
JAVA3.5
```

Here's another sample input with more "Java" values and is also out of sequence:

```
~ $  MinNumber="JAVA9, JAVA3.5, JAVA3, JAVA4.0, JAVA5"
~ $ echo $MinNumber | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/,//' | sort | head -1
JAVA3
```