# Parsing XML attributes with bash

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I need to grab attributes from the XML file with pure bash script.

So I have the following XML file with a root element `Group` and lots of `Person` elements, every of them has `id` and `username` attributes. `id` is unique value for each element:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group id="D_8"
       main="false">

    <Person id="P_0001"
            email="email0001@example.com"
            username="person_0001"
            password="pass_0001"
            active="true"/>

    <Person id="P_0002"
            email="email0002@example.com"
            username="person_0002"
            password="pass_0002"
            active="true"/>

    <!--  ...and hundreds of other Person elements ...  -->
</Group>
```

And I need to use bash script to extract the `id` and `username` attributes into some key-value structure:

```
P_0001=person_0001
P_0002=person_0002
```

Checked other related answers, but most of them suggest to use some XML parsers like xmllint. But unfortunately I do not have them on the target machine.

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: Perl/PHP are out? awk?

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: Is not it possible to use the pure bash without any additional libs?

Comment: Yes, but an XML file with the same content can also be formatted completely differently and this then causes problems. This problem does not exist if you use tools that can interpret XML files correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `username` attribute does not come before `id` attribute, this is a bash script to give the result:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

id='\bid="([^"]+)"'
username='\busername="([^"]+)"'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $id       ]] && idv="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    [[ $line =~ $username ]] && echo "$idv=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < data.xml
exit 0
```

It works even when `username` attribute and `id` attribute are on the same line.

Comment: Thank you very much Philippe, this is very elegant solution taking into account I cannot use `xmlstarlet` or any other lib as @Cyrus mentioned.

Comment: Apologies, I might have missed something, but when I run this script against my XML file `data.xml` I do not get any output.

Comment: How did you you run the script ? what's your bash version : `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: I have created `script.sh` file, pasted the content there, and then run it as usual. `data.xml` file is in the same location. I am currently running it on my macos and the bash version here is `3.2.57(1)-release`. I will on RHEL machine once I have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- the xml file is 'nicely' formatted as the presented example (hence no need for a XML parser)
- `Person id` and `username` are spelled exactly as presented and only show up in the `Group` section

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'"' '
/Person id/ { pid=$2 ; next }
/username/  { printf "%s=%s\n", pid, $2 ; next }
' xml.dat
```

Where:

- `-F '""` - use double quotes (") as our field delimiter
- `/Person id/` - store field #2 in variable `pid`
- `/username/` - print our variable `pid` + '=' + the username (again, field #2)
- `xml.dat` - name of XML file

Running this `awk` solution against the sample data file generates:

```
P_0001=person_0001
P_0002=person_0002
```

All bets are off if my assumptions are invalid.