# How parse junit report in Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, junit

Help me please, the assembly is freestyle, I can't install additional plugins, just use what I have.

The main problem is with the parse junit report, from this report, i need to transfer some data for subsequent transmission to telegram via curl.

I can only use bash or shell in step build, can anyone have a similar script for this?
url
http://jenkins_url/lastbuild/testReport/api/json
or
http://jenkins_url/lastbuild/testReport/api/xml

on the output you need to get text, succes, error, passed, total, and a list of all text.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean how to parse xml in bash?

This question already has some answers, such as
[How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash)