# How to create an XML Parser?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, nmap

**Situation:**

I am using Nmap to do network scanning and would like to create a script that takes some Nmap output in XML and parses it and based on that prints the information I want.

**Problem Description:**

This parser should:

- Be able to be to take a given input and produce an output
- The input should be an XML File.
- The output should be one of these 2 things:

  1. Be able to print text on the terminal
  2. Be able to output processed information to a text file, or an HTML one.

**Conclusion:**

I need to build a parser that has the above-mentioned functionality, how do I implement it?
Or, if possible, is there any ready-built solution that has the required functionality?

**Edit 1:**
I would like to use a bash script, and a bash script is the most preferred answer, but I am open to other languages also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind for processing nmap results is [Zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/), but that's more of a GUI for nmap. You might want to check out [nmap-parse](https://github.com/jonny1102/nmap-parse), it's a commandline tool that seems to provide what you want; although I've never used it myself so I cannot vouch for it.

I should point out that if you are somewhat familiar with Python creating a custom script to parse nmap output is pretty simple. Here is example I created after looking through the documentation of Python [xml module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) and the [nmap XML output](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('output.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for host in filter(lambda h: h.tag == 'host', root):
    status = host.find('status')
    address = host.find('address')
    print('Host', address.attrib['addr'], 'is', status.attrib['state'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but is there a way to implement this using bash scripting?

Comment: Also, this tool looks good, and I will post an edit or answer when I have tested it and it does the job.

Comment: Although technically possible, parsing xml within bash is kind of a controversial topic (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash)) I highly doubt it will leave you with a script as simple as the Python one.

Comment: Actually, that link had my solution, but also thanks a lot for the python alternative. I have marked this answer as accepted.