# Shell Script Retrieve Data from html tag

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get value inside `</em>4,519</a>` tag via shell script anyone please help how can do that?

```
id='idusedMemory' alt='graph'/></em>4,519</a> Mb / 64,309 Mb&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>
```

Comment: Your tag closes but does not open :-)

Comment: Yes , from HTML large file want just this value!

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` that supports/has the `-P` flag.

```
grep -Po '(?<=</em>).*(?=</a>)' file
```

or

```
echo 'id='idusedMemory' alt='graph'/></em>4,519</a> Mb / 64,309 Mb&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>' | grep -Po '(?<=</em>).*(?=</a>)'
```

---

As what was suggested in the comments, don't parse html/xml with such tools. Use a tool/utility for parsing such files.

Comment: Very much appreciate your answer , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `grep` with the `-o` switch in order only to show that information:

```
grep -o "</em>.*</a>" test.txt
```

`.*` stands for any number of any character.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML string containing only one substring like that, you can use regexp and `sed`:

```bash
echo "id='idusedMemory' alt='graph'/></em>4,519</a> Mb / 64,309 Mb&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>" | sed -rn 's@^.*</em>(.*)</a>.*$@\1@p'
```

Output:

```
4,519
```

If you have something more complicated, you may want to check parsing XML in bash. E.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash).

Hope that helps.